# altering of line opacity based on a variable in R - ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following code in which I would like to change the line opacity based on a variable called pop in my dataset:

```
ggplot(gapminder, aes(x = year, y = lifeExp, color = continent)) + geom_line(aes(group = country))
```

I am not sure what to add to this code in order to change the line opacity according to population? Thank you,

Comment: Hello, can you show a bit of you data, and the plot that you obtained so far, so we can help you more properly

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `alpha`:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder)
ggplot(gapminder, aes(year, lifeExp, color = continent, group = country, alpha = pop)) +
        geom_line()
```

[image]